# File include error while using Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino-nano

I am using the code below to interface the Arduino nano and android cell phone to enable serial communication through the USB port. I downloaded the filter library from GitHub https://github.com/JonHub/Filters

I am getting an error saying thet the library is not found.
I would really appreciate some suggestions on this.

Here is my code:

```
 //This code is for arduino communicating to android phone through USb serial port.
 //For arduino nano

 #include <Filters.h>   //implements digital filters which mimic the analog filter, keep track of variable statistics in realtime

char data_read; //character datatype takes up to 1 byte of memory
unsigned int analog_out;
unsigned long time;
float filterFrequency = 10.0;
FilterOnePole lowpassFilter( LOWPASS, filterFrequency );//implements digital RC type filter; both highpass and lowpass

 void setup()
 {
  Serial.begin(115200); //open the serial port and set the baud rate for communication
  // create a one pole (RC) lowpass filter

 }
 void loop()
 {
 }

 void serialEvent() { //Used when data is unavailable yet
 if (Serial.available()) //checks the number of bytes available for reading from the serial port
 {
data_read = Serial.read();

if (data_read == '0') {
  Serial.print("#");

  //Serial.print("10100");
  analog_out = lowpassFilter.input( analogRead(0) );
  Serial.print(analog_out + 10000);

  Serial.print(":");

  //Serial.print("20200");
  analog_out = lowpassFilter.input( analogRead(1) );
  Serial.print(analog_out + 20000);

  Serial.print(":");

  //Serial.print("30300");
  analog_out = lowpassFilter.input( analogRead(2) );
  Serial.print(analog_out + 30000);

  Serial.print("p");
}
/*if(data_read == '0' || data_read == '1' || data_read == '2' || data_read == '3' || data_read == '4' || data_read == '5'){
  analog_out = lowpassFilter.input( analogRead( data_read-48 ) );
  Serial.print((analog_out)+(data_read-48)*10000);
  Serial.print(":");
  }else if(data_read =='p'){
  Serial.print("p");
  }*/
   }
 }
```

Here is my error message:

```
  Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P"

  C:\Users\daphn\Documents\Arduino\Analog_Serial_out\Analog_Serial_out.ino:4:129: fatal error: Filters.h: No such file or directory

  #include <Filters.h>   //implements digital filters which mimic the analog filter, keep track of variable statistics in realtime

                                                                                                                                 ^

  compilation terminated.

  exit status 1
  Error compiling for board Arduino Nano.

  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
   option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: And where did you put the library?

Comment: I've included the library in the same folder where I had saved my code

Comment: Have you read these 2 pages? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC6 , https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Answer (score -1):

You have to put the folder with the library files in the folder `libraries` under your sketchbook folder. Then the IDE should be able to find them.

I think there is also a possibility to save them in the same folder as your `.ino` file, but it I don't know how exactly you have to do this.

Comment: I did try including the filters.h header file under the main libraries folder, but still I get the same error. I am wondering if there is any mistake with the source of the header file itself. Usually, when I include external libraries, I place it in the same folder as the code itself and it works.

Comment: I tested it with your code and the linked library and it works for me. Check in the IDEs settings, to where the sketchbook folder is set

Comment: The library is more than a .h file. You need ALL the files, and all placed in a folder named Filters within your libraries folder in your sketchbook. Nothing else will do.

Comment: @Majenko What do you mean by ALL the files?

Comment: @DaphFab All the files for the library. Everything in that github repository. All the .h files, all the .cpp files, etc. There's 11 of them, plus examples.

Comment: Ok got it. I had already done that before. Anyway, I solved the issue by changing `#include <Filters.h>` to `#include "Filters.h"`

Comment: please elaborate why you did that, so that people can resolve similar issues in the future

Answer (score -1):

Here is your definitive answer.

You have to do the #include like the following (with double-quotes, not < > brackets)

`#include "Filters.h"`

This will make Arduino compiler look in the project folder.

Using < > brackets tells the compiler that it is in the standard library area.

I just tested this with the following script.

```
#include "mytest.h"
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

The `mytest.h` file is blank (has no text in it).

It wouldn't work until I included it using the double-quotes method.